# Flex mobile : how to know it is the very first time running the application

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I googled but didn't find a post for Flex mobile..
All I want for now is display an user agreement popup from TabbedViewNavigatorApplication when the user uses the app for the first time

```
var agreementView: UserAgreement = new UserAgreement();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(agreementView, this,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(agreementView);
```

but maybe more later.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

What i did in my desktop air app;
I guess this will work at a mobile app also.

Make sure you have write access; 
open yourproject-app.mxml scroll down to the end of the document. In the  section, uncomment the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Now you can create files like for example an sqlite database.

At the applicationcomplete call the function checkFirstRun:

```
    //  functions to check if the application is run for the first time (also after updates)
    // so important structural changes can be made here.
    public var file:File;
    public var currentVersion:Number;   
    private function checkFirstRun():void
    {
    //get the current application version.
    currentVersion=getApplicationVersion();

        //get versionfile
        file = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
        file= file.resolvePath("Preferences/version.txt");
        if(file.exists)
        {
            checkVersion();
        }
        else
        {
            firstRun(); // create the version file.
        }
    }

        public function getApplicationVersion():Number
        {
            var appXML:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
            var ns:Namespace = appXML.namespace();
            var versionnumber:Number =Number(appXML.ns::versionNumber);
            return versionnumber;       
        }
private function checkVersion():void
{
    var stream:FileStream= new FileStream();
    stream.open(file,FileMode.READ);
    var prevVersion:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
    stream.close();
    if(Number(prevVersion)<currentVersion)
    {
        // if the versionnumber inside the file is older than the current version we go and run important code.
        // like alternating the structure of tables inside the sqlite database file.
        runImportantCode();

        //after running the important code, we set the version to the currentversion. 
        saveFile(currentVersion);
    }   
}
private function firstRun():void
{
    // at the first time, we set the file version to 0, so the important code will be executed. 
    var firstVersion:Number=0;
    saveFile(firstVersion);

    // we also run the checkversion so important code is run right after installing an update
    //(and the version file doesn't exist before the update).
    checkFirstRun();
}

private function saveFile(currentVersion:Number):void
{
    var stream:FileStream=new FileStream();
    stream.open(file,FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(String(currentVersion));
    stream.close();
}


private function runImportantCode():void
{
    // here goes important code.
    // make sure you check if the important change previously has been made or not, because this code is run after each update.

}
```

Hope this helps.
Greets, J.

Answer (score 0):

Some you need to store whether the user has agreed to the agreement or not.  IF they haven't agreed, then show it.

One way to do this would be to store a value in a shared object.  Another way to do this would be to use a remote service and store such data in a central repository.  I assume you'll want the second; so you can do some form of tracking against the number of users using your app.

Comment: Thanks, I love the simplest way. Is that serializing a ContextData object into file system and restore it at startup. If it is null, then it is the 1st time ?

Comment: side question please :P : The popup doesn't cover the main view behind it. It looks like a mess! Could you hint me the simplest way to show this user agreement. Note: I already have 2 tab-systems. One for login/register, another for Main App..

Comment: Yes, Shared Objects are in essence a local data store for small amounts of data.  Analogous to a browser cookie.  View the docs on Shared Objects: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html .  I can't comment on the visual display of your app with the popup without seeing screenshots.